# Evaluating Given Probabilities

Tags: probability

So I have the following data from a Machine Learning Algorithm. How can I know which of the following has the highest chance of happening? Sorry, if the question is naive, some explanation will also help as my probability background is damn weak:

```
Scored Probabilities for Class BackPocket: 5.75198682781775E-05
Scored Probabilities for Class Ear: 8.09076100792557E-21
Scored Probabilities for Class Handbag: 8.43800620486945E-08
Scored Probabilities for Class SidePocket: 0.999963939189911
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: The "$E-\text{number}$" at the end stands for "$\times \dfrac1{10^{\text{number}}}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything adds up to $1$ (meaning the event will occur with $100\%$ probability). So you just take the largest one. In your case $$0.999963939189911$$